# Location of Python log file should be changed

Tags: python, python-2.7, logging

I am using logger in my python 2.7 project on a legacy code. I want to create logs on specific location but python logging module creates the log files at the default place i.e. from where it is executed.

Is there is any way to change this default location?
Below is the initialization of the logger.

```
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)

formatter = logging.Formatter('%(message)s')

file_handler = logging.FileHandler('file.log')
file_handler.setFormatter(formatter)

logger.addHandler(file_handler)
```

Comment: It's as simple as giving the right location of the log file including a path.

Comment: @KlausD.How do I include the path then? Would you share the code?

Answer (score 0):

Below is an example of how you can set the location and other properties of Python logger:

- You can define a `get_logger` function as follows:

```
import logging
import os

LOG_DIR = 'log_dir'
LOG_FORMATTER = logging.Formatter('[%(asctime)s] %(levelname)s %(name)s: %(message)s')

def get_logger(log_name, log_dir = LOG_DIR):
    if not os.path.isdir(log_dir):
        os.mkdir(log_dir)
    logger = logging.getLogger(log_name)
    logging.basicConfig(level = logging.INFO)

    log_handler = logging.FileHandler(os.path.join(log_dir, log_name))
    logger.addHandler(log_handler)
    log_handler.setFormatter(LOG_FORMATTER)
    log_handler.setLevel('INFO')

    return logger
```

- Then in the file that you want to make logs, you can do as follows:

```
logger = get_logger('filename')
```

- If you want to make a logging message, you can then do as follows:

```
logger.info('logging information!')
```